# Finding a suitable Transformation for data

Tags: r

Here's my data:

```
y = c(-0.1, -0.35, -0.2, -0.35, 0.1, 4, 0.55, 1.85, 0.05, 0.25, 0.15, -0.2, 0.2, 3.4, 0.4, 1.15)
```

I had tried many transformation already, like log, square root, squaring, and cubic, but the variance of one of the factor still does not meet the equal variance. Or am I doing the transformation wrong?

```
s2=apply(data,1,var)  
lns2=log(apply(data,1,var))  
sq2=(apply(data,1,var)^2)
```

I also get something like this:

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

What should I do now?
*Edit: so my goal is to transform the data to achieve the assumption of equal variance and normality.

Comment: What do you mean by equal variance? Also, could you please add the output of `dput(data)` to your post.

Comment: like we need to meet the assumption of equal variance, and what is dput(data) ? sorry.

Comment: `dput` is a command that outputs an expression that can reproduce the data.  `data` here is the variable you are calculating the variance on. What data structure are you using? If `y` is your data, why are you applying `var` on `data`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `scale`?

```
scaled <- scale(y)

> var(scaled)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
> mean(scaled)
[1] -8.673617e-19
```

Comment: No, I haven't ! But I figure it our already, I end up using tangent ! Thanks!